# i cant install vscode in elementry os 6.1 stable

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, installation, terminal

i try install vs code, but appear:./code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ./code_1.67.2-1652812855_amd64.deb: line 1:` ! arch '
everyone can help me ??
i use elementry OS 6.1 stable.

Comment: You are using Arch-based linux, so check this out. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AUR_helpers , the vscode is called https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin

Answer (score 0):

Install yay or paru or something else.

then

```bash
yay
```

or

```bash
paru
```

to Syu your repo.

then

```bash
yay -S visual-studio-code-bin
```

or

```bash
paru -S visual-studio-code-bin
```